# Getting vue-warn in all the vuetify 3 components related to VOverlay (v-dialog, v-tooltip, v-overlay)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-cli

I am using Vue 3 with Vuetify 3.0.1. I want to develop a Vue application based on Options API. While trying to make use of a simple v-dialog, I getting following error:

```
    runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:40 [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of watcher callback 
  at <VOverlay ref=Ref< undefined > class="v-dialog" width="500"  ... > 
  at <VDialog modelValue=false onUpdate:modelValue=fn width="500" > 
  at <VMain> 
  at <VApp> 
  at <App>
warn @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:40
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:40 [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of setup function 
  at <VOverlay ref=Ref< undefined > class="v-dialog" width="500"  ... > 
  at <VDialog modelValue=false onUpdate:modelValue=fn width="500" > 
  at <VMain> 
  at <VApp> 
  at <App>


Uncaught TypeError: globalStack.at is not a function
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vuetify/lib/composables/stack.mjs:36)
    at callWithErrorHandling (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:286)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:295)
    at ReactiveEffect.getter [as fn] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:1858)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.esm-bundler.js:225)
    at doWatch (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:1973)
    at watchEffect (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:1778)
    at useStack (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vuetify/lib/composables/stack.mjs:34)
    at Object.setup [as _setup] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VOverlay/VOverlay.mjs:151)
    at setup (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vuetify/lib/util/defineComponent.mjs:62)
```

My setup configuration is not that complex.

App.Vue

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog">
      <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
        <v-btn color="primary" v-bind="props"> Open Dialog </v-btn>
      </template>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      dialog: false,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

main.ts

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import store from "./store/planner";
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import i18n from "./i18n";

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(vuetify).use(router).use(store).use(i18n);
app.mount("#app");
```

This occurs on all the vuetify components involving v-overlay.

Comment: Probably a bug in Vuetify 3. Try to investigate through the callstack and eventually put breakpoints inside the Vuetify code to see what exactly is causing the problem.